# Mongodb 3.4 - fail to start mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How can I start mongodb.  The child process fail.

```
-bash-4.1$ mongod --config /mongodb/etc/mongod-ctr.conf 
 about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 22965

ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 48

-bash-4.1$ mongo
          MongoDB shell version v3.4.17
          connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
          2018-11-27T13:52:13.826-0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to 
          connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after 
          poll), reason: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MongoDB error code manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/), and your error status, there seems to be another process either running on port 27017, or you just don't have the right permissions.

You can use the command `lsof -i -P -n` to see a list of all applications, and the ports they are using.